# python interrupt infinite loop in exec'd script in thread

Tags: python, asynchronous, abort

A GUI application allows the user to write a Python script, then run it (via exec). Problem is that if the user, by mistake (I'm not concerned with ill intention, just honest coding mistakes on the part of the user) the script contains an infinite loop, control will never return to my application. A keyboard interrupt doesn't work because of the GUI.

I have identified four ways to handle this:

1. Tracing: use sys.settrace so a function gets called at every line; in there, I could put logic that attempts to identify if the same segment of code is being executed over and over (how challenging this would be in practice I don't know yet). I would guess that this could slow down execution speed considerably.
2. Asynchronous exception: run the script in a separate thread and, using ctypes, have main thread use PyThreadState_SetAsyncExc to raise an exception in the script thread to kick it out of its loop (see https://gist.github.com/liuw/2407154 and http://tomerfiliba.com/recipes/Thread2/). Then the part of thread that called exec would recover control and could take appropriate action (show message to user etc). I know, threads should not be aborted from the outside but here, even if doing this leaves the objects that were being changed by the script in an undefined state, at least it would allow the GUI to throw out the objects that are no longer reliable (it can do that because all modifications accessible to script are in one big object that could be thrown out and reloaded from disk).
3. Separate process: using multiprocessing module, would run the script in a separate process; however the script can contain calls to objects that live in the parent's main thread so this is going to get quite complicated.
4. Daemonic thread: run script in daemonic thread, then if script doean't return after a certain period, consider it "hung". When the application exits, the thread will continue to run and the user can forcibly kill it via task manager (or the exiting thread could, by raising SystemException or such).

So the question: If I have to provide this feature, which one of the above methods is the lesser of all evils? Are there other techniques yet, not in the above 4?

Comment: I think your main issue is that you're allowing a user script to access objects that live in your main application namespace. Providing a managed API which the user script can access will allow you to make it thread/process-safe, making running that script in a separate process *no big deal*. :)

Comment: @JoelCornett Can you clarify how thread safety will enable me to interrupt an infinite loop? In a Python shell, you can ctrl-c an infinite loop, because it runs in the main thread. But here the main thread runs the GUI, and the second thread runs the scripts; they will only have access to objects also in second thread. Unless I'm missing something, there is no thread safety involved here. The issue is that I can't run the script in the main thread, where infinite loops can be interrupted (break or SIGINT etc), and there is no "standard" way for me to interrupt non-main threads.

Comment: If you run the code in a separate *process*, you can send it interrupt signals. By thread/process safety, I meant implementing an IPC mechanism to allow API calls to occur between the user script process and the main process.

Comment: @JoelCornett Ah, so how is this different from item 3 of my question?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is with a custom `multiprocessing.Manager` object.  It can handle the synchronization for you.  (link: [multiprocessing](http://devdocs.io/python/library/multiprocessing#multiprocessing.sharedctypes.multiprocessing.Manager))

Here's an example of having a single instance, with multiprocess processes able to call methods on it.  Note I'm not using instance state, that's left up to the reader :)

The original code was passing "maths.add" (instance method) to the Pool, but methods aren't picklable. Thus I created the global "my_add", which accepts a maths instance (which *is* pickable), then some numbers which it adds together and results the result.

### source

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager

class MathsClass(object):
    def add(self, x, y):
        return x + y
    def mul(self, x, y):
        return x * y

class MyManager(BaseManager):
    pass

MyManager.register('Maths', MathsClass)

def my_add(mobj, *args):
    return mobj.add(*args)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager = MyManager()
    manager.start()
    maths = manager.Maths()

    # pass the shared 'maths' object into each process

    pool = Pool()
    print pool.apply(my_add, [maths, 4, 3])
    # print maths.add(4, 3)         # prints 7
    print pool.apply(my_add, [maths, 7, 8])
    # print maths.mul(7, 8)         # prints 56
```

### output

```
7
15
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But how is this different from alternative #3 of my question?

Comment: I think it is a suggestion like the original commentator's, that in #3 it is better to pass stuff into your process, behind some manager facade, than to really share.  Of course this is hard if the point is to synchronize with the changes to those objects owned by the main process.  (So I think you have, so far three implicit upvotes for #3, with attempted assurances that sharing is not that bad.)

Comment: +1 If maths class has state, and changes in its state get automatically reflected across processes, then that could be an interesting option, albeit there could be significant overhead in shipping such state data between main and aux processes, and possibly a fair bit of work to make the state itrms shippable (some will be complex tree structures that may change as a result of running the script).

Answer (score 1):

How about letting the Python code remain the main thread and spawning a worker thread that will sleep and then interrupt the main thread with SIGINT.

When the user process finishes, you can kill the worker.  But if the worker fires, you will get the equivalent of a keyboard interrupt, so you can catch the resulting exception and clean up.

That way you do not have memory problems sharing your stuff with the main program, but you still get poked after a fixed period in a way that kills the runaway subprogram.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately the main thread runs the GUI, so I can't run the script there (in case the scripts do take more than a split second, which could make the GUI frustrating to use as scripts are run many times per second in some cases). It appears that SIGINT and co can only fire in the main thread, so will not interrupt the other threads, so even if the GUI is "notified" that something is wrong, GUI can't do anything about it. Or am I missing something from your answer?

Comment: Nope, I was just trying to suggest you flip the fork suggested in option #3, to keep more namespace accessible, since that seemed to be a concern.  I did not realize that your scripts were that pervasive.

Answer (score 0):

As much as option 1 is disparaged in general, options 2 or 4 and 1 would combine nicely.

You could spawn a thread which would install your `settrace` callback and continue with the loading and execution of the script code module inside some kind of try/catch wrapper.

The implementation of `settrace` would not need to attempt analysis, just check the age of its own thread, and if it is too old, throw an exception.

The wrapper code could then inform the GUI of the timeout.

I guess part of the point here is that you might want to execute the user's script not directly with `exec`, but by loading the module inside something you `exec`, so you can pack Python code around it, including try/except blocks, and installation of things like settrace or `Timer` threads that can inject cues, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you know beforehand exactly what the code will be that will execute, using #1 `settrace` to decide whether the code is actually still active, will be hard, and yes will slow down the executing code, possibly considerably, depending on what the code is for. See the [halting problem](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Halting_problem).

Option #3 is the best (semi combine with #4). That is what separate processes are for -- doing work separately, while letting the first process get on with other things. It is not difficult to set up.

The new process (P2) does not have to contain calls to objects that live in the GUI, concerns should be separated. That does not mean that they cannot interact. Use a socket-pair for communication, for example, with both sides using `pickle` to send even python objects to each other. The GUI main loop should schedule a check every e.g. 50ms, that checks its socket, which is set to non-blocking, for communication from P2. P2 can then send messages to the GUI if it likes, to which the GUI will respond.

P2 executes the code in a new process, P3 (not absolutely necessary, but better setup). P2 also checks for commands from the GUI (periodically, if you want), commands such as 'stop the execution of the script' when a stop button is used in the GUI, for which P2 can then do an `os.kill(P3ID..)` or `P3.terminate()` if using `multiprocessing` etc. Or it can also send commands to the GUI and receive back the data that it needs, GUI will respond (start responding) in max 50ms.

Code below is all just partial snippets, not tested at all, just to give you an idea of the architecture. It's better to separate into different parts, e.g. a `SocketCom` class for wrapping around every socket, which encapsulates the converting of data to bytes using `pickle`, and sending it using the underlying socket, or receiving single messages in either blocking or non-blocking mode for the `select`, using the underlying socket to receive and unpickle the message before it is passed back, etc.

### General code

```py
sGUI, s2 = socket.socketpair(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SEQPACKET)
sGUI.setblocking(False) # for direct use, but will raise system-dependent errors, better to use select
P2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=P2process, args=(s2,codeToRun) )

def P2process (sock, codeToRun) :
    # sock is the socket connected to GUI socket
    P3 = multiprocessing.Process(target=P3process, args=(codeToRun,) ) # note, args is tuple
    # block (up to you) for messages from/to GUI, check P3 periodically, etc.
    # e.g. can do :
    sock.sendall(pickle.dumps("sendMeX"))
    X = pickle.loads(sock.recv(length))
    # or e.g. a blocking loop that responds only to messages from GUI :
    while True :
        msg = pickle.loads(sock.recv(length))
        if msg == 'status' :
            sock.sendall(pickle.dumps(P3.is_alive()))
        elif msg == 'stop' :
            P3.terminate()
        elif msg == 'newExecCode' :
            newExecCode = pickle.loads(sock.recv(length))
        elif msg == 'quit' :
            P3.terminate()
            break
    ...

def P3process (codeToRun) :
    exec(codeToRun) # you should sandbox its context with custom globals & locals
    # up to you how to solve the halting problem ;)
    # user probably decides and GUI has 'stop' button if exec takes too long
```

### For GUI :

GUI can send commands to P2 whenever, using `sGUI`, e.g. on button click. For listening for messages from P2, it would look something like this:

```py
def GUI_P2Com_loop (self) :
    # this is called once, and at the end of the function, it registers itself as a
    # callback to be called again after a timeout. It checks for messages from P2, 
    # and responds as necessary. It can also launch other processes to respond instead.
    try :
        reads, w, x = select.select([sGUI], [], [], 0) # 0 = non-blocking
        if sGUI in reads :
            msg = pickle.loads(sGUI.recv(length))
            # got message from P2, do whatever
            if msg == 'sendMeX' :
                sGUI.sendall(pickle.dumps(X))
    ...

    # so that the GUI can get on with responding to user interaction
    # all GUI frameworks should have a function for registering a callback after timeout
    # e.g. a tkinter widget would call :
    self._job = widget.after(50, GUI_P2Com_loop) # where widget could be self if class extends widget
```

the `_job` is stored so that the communication loop can be cancelled with e.g. tkinter again :

```py
def cancel_com_loop (self) :
    self.after_cancel(self._job)
```

See the [tkinter effbot documentation](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm).